# React - Define greater string between objects

Tags: javascript

I am calculating the average score of each object ( team ) in my array.

This is my data structure:

```
const scores = [
  { day: "1", Barcelona: 1, Real: 3, Valencia: 0 },
  { day: "2", Barcelona: 4, Real: 6, Valencia: 3 },
  { day: "3", Barcelona: 7, Real: 7, Valencia: 3 },
  { day: "4", Barcelona: 7, Real: 8, Valencia: 6 }
];
```

This is how i calculate the average

```
const getAverage = team => {
  if (isNaN(scores[0][team])) return null;

  return scores.map(x => x[team]).reduce((a, c) => a + c) / scores.length;
};
```

I need to establish the object team with the greater number which is the stronger team. How can i do that ?

The stronger team is the team with the higher average.

Here i have done a prototype to reproduce the scenario: https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-examples-y0y7q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the maxAverage from array of teams like so:

```js
this.state = {
    homeCity: "Barcelona",
    awayCity: "Valencia"
}

const scores = [
    { day: "1", Barcelona: 1, Real: 3, Valencia: 0 },
    { day: "2", Barcelona: 4, Real: 6, Valencia: 3 },
    { day: "3", Barcelona: 7, Real: 7, Valencia: 3 },
    { day: "4", Barcelona: 7, Real: 8, Valencia: 6 }
  ];

const getAverage = team => {
    if (isNaN(scores[0][team])) return null;

    return scores.map(x => x[team]).reduce((a, c) => a + c) / scores.length;
};

const maxAverage = teams => {
    return teams.map(team => {
        return {
            team:team, 
            avg: getAverage(team)
        }
    }).reduce((a,b)=>a.avg>b.avg?a:b).team
}

console.log(maxAverage([this.state.homeCity,this.state.awayCity]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your code, loop through the first element to get all the keys, filter out day key so we left with all the team name, map through team names and get average and then sort

```js
const scores = [
  { day: "1", Barcelona: 1, Real: 3, Valencia: 0 },
  { day: "2", Barcelona: 4, Real: 6, Valencia: 3 },
  { day: "3", Barcelona: 7, Real: 7, Valencia: 3 },
  { day: "4", Barcelona: 7, Real: 8, Valencia: 6 }
];

const getAverage = team => {
  if (isNaN(scores[0][team])) return null;
  return scores.map(x => x[team]).reduce((a, c) => a + c) / scores.length
};

let stronger = Object.entries(scores[0])
                     .filter(([key, value]) => key !== 'day')
                     .map(([key, value]) => [key, getAverage(key)])
                     .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])

console.log(stronger)
```